# Reading a file in, then writing out a file with similar name in R

Tags: r

In R, I would like to read in data from a file, then do a bunch of stuff, then write out data to another file.  I can do that.  But I'd like to have the two files have similar names automatically.

e.g. if I create a file params1.R I can read it in with

```
source("c:\\personal\\consults\\ElwinWu\\params1.R")
```

then do a lot of stuff

then write out a resulting table with write.table and a filename similar to above, except with output1 instead of params1.

But I will be doing this with many different params files, and I can foresee making careless mistakes of not changing the output file to match the params file.   Is there a way to automate this?

That is, set the number for output to match the number for params?

thanks

Peter

Comment: Let's see the function in params1.R (or at least the part related to data import). It would be way easier to suggest what to do if we see how data import is implemented.

Comment: OK, I finally had some time to try this, but I got one of R's infamous error messages: > patients2 <- as.table(patients)
> write.table(patients2, gsub("params","output",file) )
Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is just to make sure that all the outputs go in the same directory as the input then try this:

```
source(file <- "c:\\personal\\consults\\ElwinWu\\params1.R")

old.dir <- setwd(dirname(file))

write.table(...whatever..., file = "output1.dat")
write.table(...whatever..., file = "output2.dat")

setwd(old.dir)
```

If you don't need to preserve the initial directory you can omit the last line.

Answer (score 3):

If your source file always contains "params" which you want to change to "output" then you can easilly do this with `gsub`:

```
source(file <- "c:\\personal\\consults\\ElwinWu\\params1.R")

### some stuff

write.table(youroutput, gsub("params","output",file) )
# Will write in "c:\\personal\\consults\\ElwinWu\\output1.R"
```

## Edit:

Or to get .txt as filetype:

```
write.table(youroutput, gsub(".R",".txt",gsub("params","output",file)))
# Will output in c:\\personal\\consults\\ElwinWu\\output1.txt"
```

## Edit2:

And a loop for 20 param files then would be:

```
n <- 20 # number of files

for (i in 1:n)
{
    source(file <- paste("c:\\personal\\consults\\ElwinWu\\params",i,".R",sep=""))

    ### some stuff

    write(youroutput, gsub(".R",".txt",gsub("params","output",file)))
}
```

Comment: You could also use `source(file<-file.choose())` if you are working interactively and don't want to keep writing out filenames.

Comment: Didn't know you could assign like that, nice. Edited it in my answer